# How do I keep my solution explorer window scoped in Visual Studio 2013?

Tags: visual-studio

I like to keep my solution explorer window scoped to a particular subfolder since my project is quite large. When I have to restart Visual Studio 2013, it always returns to the default scope. Creating new solution explorer view has the same problem. How do I keep the settings?  I tried to use Layout O Rama and it doesn't solve either of these problems.

Comment: did you find any solution on this?

Comment: just found a user voice suggestion, would nice to have some more votes: [user voice](https://visualstudio.uservoice.com/forums/121579-visual-studio/suggestions/5312265-make-solution-explorer-remember-its-new-view)